# How to get Adapter Name with Indy?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I can get all local IP addresses using this code with indy:

```
uses IdStack;

var
  IPs: TStringList;
begin
  IPs := TStringList.Create;
  try
    GStack.AddLocalAddressesToList(IPs);
    listbox_localIPs.Items.Assign(IPs);  //My listbox
  finally
    IPs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

How can I get **Adapter Name** for each IP I find with Indy?

Answer (score 3):

Indy doesn't provide such info. You must use WinApi ([`GetAdaptersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917.aspx), [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx)) or WMI ([`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

Indy is primarily just a wrapper around standard socket APIs that do not expose adapter information.  `AddLocalAddressesToList()` uses platform-specific APIs to get the local IPs, and some of those APIs may report adapter names (or expose ways to look up those names through other APIs), but `AddLocalAddressesToList()` simply fills a `TStrings` with IP address strings, so it has no way of reporting adapter names even if it wanted to.

With that said, [`AddLocalAddressesToList()` has recently been deprecated](http://indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/changeLog/20140314A.aspx) in favor of a new `GetLocalAddressList()` method, which returns a collection of `TIdStackLocalAddress`-derived objects containing additional information (IP version, subnet mask).  So it is feasible that a future release might add adapter names, but that would still be implemented on a platform-specific basis and thus may not be available on all platforms.  Indy itself does not need adapter names, so you are best off simply using platform-specific APIs directly to get whatever adapter information you need.